# working with a NSFetchedResult controller and section headers for each month

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting a different section for each month with fetchedresultcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815093/setting-a-different-section-for-each-month-with-fetchedresultcontroller)

I am trying to split my **UITableview** into sections for each month. I start working with the [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) example of apple. First of all I added in my **coredata** a attribute 'sectionIdentifier'.  Then in my **managedobject** subclass I added this method.

```
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier {

    // Create and cache the section identifier on demand.

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp) {
        /*
         Sections are organized by month and year. Create the section identifier as a string representing the number (year * 1000) + month; this way they will be correctly ordered chronologically regardless of the actual name of the month.
         */
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:[self date]];
        tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ([components year] * 1000) + [components month]];
          [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
    }
    NSLog(@"tmp: %@",tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

This is what i do in my titleForHeaderSection

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];


    /*
     Section information derives from an event's sectionIdentifier, which is a string representing the number (year * 1000) + month.
     To display the section title, convert the year and month components to a string representation.
     */
    static NSArray *monthSymbols = nil;

    if (!monthSymbols) {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
        monthSymbols = [formatter monthSymbols];
    }

    NSInteger numericSection = [[theSection name] integerValue];

    NSInteger year = numericSection / 1000;
    NSInteger month = numericSection - (year * 1000);

    NSString *titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", [monthSymbols objectAtIndex:month-1], year];
    NSLog(@"titelstring is: %@",titleString);
    return titleString;
}
```

For my number of rowsInSection I do this.

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

        NSInteger count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        return count;
```

And this for my NumberOfSectionsInTableview

```
NSInteger count = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
        return count;
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

**What is going wrong**

First off all it don't prints my log in NSLog(@"tmp: %@",tmp); 
And also I get the following error:

```
**CoreData**: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) A section returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'. Objects will be placed in unnamed section
2012-10-10 10:41:17.475 RacingGenk[15785:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (-1 (or possibly larger)) beyond bounds (12)'
```

**EDIT**
Here is where I set my NSFetchresultcontroller

```
- (void)getKalender // attaches an NSFetchRequest to this UITableViewController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Kalender"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                sectionNameKeyPath:@"Kalender.sectionIdentifier" cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController;
```

Comment: I do not want to sound rude, but posting the identical question twice (same user, different account) is probably not a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815093/setting-a-different-section-for-each-month-with-fetchedresultcontroller.

Comment: If nobody is answering my question and is quite urgent. I need to ask it twice. I'm sorry.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set up the fetched results controller/ predicate/sort descriptor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be

```
sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"
```

instead of

```
sectionNameKeyPath:@"Kalender.sectionIdentifier"
```

in the construction of the fetched results controller.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I also want to thank you for all your other answers as well! You're great !